# Shellability and order filters in the partition lattice

Tags: co.combinatorics, lattice-theory, posets, partitions

Choose $n\in\mathbb N$.  Let $B$ be a non-empty subset of $[n]:=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$.  Consider the set of partitions of the set $[n]$ with exactly $|B|$ parts such that each part has exactly one member of $B$. Say this set has exactly $t$ elements.

Is there a way to list the elements of this set ($\sigma_1,\dots,\sigma_t$) so that the following holds?

> If $i,k\in\{1,2,\dots,t\}$ and $i<k$ and if there exists $\tau$ in the
> partition lattice such that $\sigma_i,\sigma_k<\tau$, then there
> exists $j\in\{1,2,\dots,k-1\}$ and there exists $\chi$ in the
> partition lattice such that $\sigma_j,\sigma_k\lessdot \chi\le\tau$, where
> "$\lessdot$" denotes the covering relation.

Recall that if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are partitions, then $\alpha\lessdot\beta$ if and only if $\beta$ is obtained from $\alpha$ by joining together two parts of $\alpha$, and $\alpha\le\beta$ if every part of $\alpha$ is a subset of a part of $\beta$.